# Expresión regular que encuentre 14 o 16 dígitos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo que realizar una expresión regular que identifique las siguientes alternativas:

```
Alternativa 1: "00-F000-00000000"

Alternativa 2: "F000-00000000"
```

Mi expresión regular no me funciona con la alternativa 2:

```
/\s?\b\d{2}[-]?[A-Z]{1}\d{3}[-]\d{8}\b\s?/gmi,
```

Comment: Haz que el primer segmento sea un grupo opcional: `(\d{2}-)?[A-Z]\d{3}-\d{8}`. Los guiones no son necesarios meterlos en conjuntos de un solo símbolo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Sal tu comentario puede ser marcado como respuesta para que otros usuarios puedan usarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La expresión regular es la siguiente:

```
/[\w-]{14}|[\w-]{16}/g
```

Mediante JavaScript puedo generar esta expresión regular. La `\w` acepta tanto números como letras... Como voy a usar más de una vez la `\w` en la expresión regular, la asigno a una variable.

Lo siguiente es parte de la expresión regular. Para esto hago una expresión regular y le quito las barras, de manera que quede como string:

```
var s = /[\w-]/.toString().slice(1,-1)
```

Para generar un string con los caracteres `"\"` y `"w"`, lo meto en una expresión regular, luego lo convierto a string, y por último quito el caracter del principio (`"/"`) y el caracter del final (`"/"`).

Ahora siguiendo ese criterio, hago una función lambda (`()=>{}`) que genere la expresión regular, usando también los template strings (``` `` ```):

```
var f = (...args) => {
  return [...args].map(x=>{
    return `[${/[\w-]/
      .toString().slice(1,-1)
    }{${x}}`
  }).join("|")
}
```

Hago la unión de las expresiones para un texto de *14* y otro de *16* caracteres mediante el caacter `"|"`.

```
[\w-]{14}
[\w-]{16}
[\w-]{14}|[\w-]{16}
```

Esta cadena de texto se usará en un `new RegExp` para generar la expresión regular:

```
var g = new RegExp("[\w-]{14}|[\w-]{16}","g")
```

Sobre la *Alternativa 2*, No funciona porque tiene *13* caracteres, en vez de *14* o *16*:

```
                          12+
                         11 |
                        10 13
                123456789   |
Alternativa 2: "F000-00000000"
```

Código:

```js
var f = (...args) => {
  return [...args].map(x=>{
    return `[${/[\w-]/
      .toString().slice(1,-1)
    }{${x}}`
  }).join("|")
}

var g = new RegExp(f(14,16),"g")

console.log(g)

var a = [
  "00-F000-00000000",
  "F000-00000000"
].map(x=>{
  return console.log( x.length, x, g.test(x) )
})
```